# Is there heartbeat, timeout or disconnection support in Dart Web Sockets?

Tags: dart, dart-html

When using Web Sockets in Dart, is there any heartbeat, timeout or disconnection support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually re-establish the connection to the server on the client after a short timeout like this:

```dart
  establishConnection() {
    connection = new WebSocket('ws://...');

    // Upon connection close, wait a while and try to re-connect.
    connection.onClose.listen((e) => new Timer(5000, (t) => establishConnection()));

    connection.onOpen.listen((_) => print('Connection to the server opened.'));
  }
```

I don't think the server can do this... because the browsers are the ones who open the connection, and web browsers such as Chrome and Firefox don't have any support for heartbeats.

Comment: BTW using new Timer like that is generally an anti-pattern. If you must use Timer, be sure to wrap the callback's implementation in a try/catch.

Comment: To see the server-side, here is some example code: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui-code-lab/blob/master/finished/bin/chat_server.dart